# How to display a cropped image like a puzzle in random order in the gamepanel in the left side and let the user solve the puzzle?

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to build a puzzle game but I can't seem to crop the image into equal parts and i dont know how to create an action listener that will transfer a particular button to the free space in the bottom-right most area of the Photo Puzzle Panel

Thanks!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.CropImageFilter;
import java.awt.image.FilteredImageSource;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class midterm extends JFrame
{
    JPanel mainpanel;
    JPanel gamepanel;
    JPanel controls;

    JButton image1=new JButton();
    JButton image2=new JButton();
    JButton image3=new JButton();
    JButton image4=new JButton();
    JButton image5=new JButton();
    JButton image6=new JButton();
    JButton image7=new JButton();
    JButton image8=new JButton();
    JButton image9=new JButton();   

    JButton j1=new JButton();

    ExitButtonListener end=new ExitButtonListener();

    JLabel text=new JLabel("Please select a photo.");
    JLabel piclabel;



    public midterm()
    {
        super("Girls' Generation - I GOT A BOY 4th Korean Album");
        setSize(700,700);
        setLocation(200,30);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);

        panel();
        this.getContentPane().add(mainpanel);
        this.pack();
        setVisible(true);   
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        midterm frame=new midterm();
    }



    void panel()
    {
        mainpanel=new JPanel();
        mainpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        gamepanel=new JPanel();
        gamepanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Photo Puzzle"));
        gamepanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));


        ImageIcon sica = new ImageIcon("jung.jpg");
        image1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
        image1.setIcon(sica);
        image1.setSize(200,200);
        image1.setVisible(true);
        image1.setToolTipText("Jessica Jung Sooyeon");
        gamepanel.add((image1));

        ImageIcon yuri = new ImageIcon("kwon.jpg");
        image2.setIcon(yuri);
        image2.setSize(200,200);
        image2.setVisible(true);
        image2.setToolTipText("Kwon Yuri");
        gamepanel.add(image2);

        ImageIcon tiff = new ImageIcon("hwang.jpg");
        image3.setIcon(tiff);
        image3.setSize(200,200);
        image3.setVisible(true);
        image3.setToolTipText("Tiffany Hwang Miyoung");
        gamepanel.add(image3);

        ImageIcon sunny = new ImageIcon("lee.jpg");
        image4.setIcon(sunny);
        image4.setSize(200,200);
        image4.setVisible(true);
        image4.setToolTipText("Sunny Lee Sunkyu");      
        gamepanel.add(image4);

        ImageIcon soo = new ImageIcon("choi.jpg");
        image5.setIcon(soo);
        image5.setSize(200,200);
        image5.setVisible(true);
        image5.setToolTipText("Choi Sooyoung");
        gamepanel.add(image5);

        ImageIcon hyo = new ImageIcon("kimh.jpg");
        image6.setIcon(hyo);
        image6.setSize(200,200);
        image6.setVisible(true);
        image6.setToolTipText("Kim Hyoyeon");
        gamepanel.add(image6);

        ImageIcon yoona = new ImageIcon("im.jpg");
        image7.setIcon(yoona);
        image7.setSize(200,200);
        image7.setVisible(true);
        image7.setToolTipText("Im Yoona");      
        gamepanel.add(image7);

        ImageIcon taeng = new ImageIcon("kimt.jpg");
        image8.setIcon(taeng);
        image8.setSize(200,200);
        image8.setVisible(true);
        image8.setToolTipText("Kim Taeyeon");
        gamepanel.add(image8);

        ImageIcon hyunnie = new ImageIcon("seo.jpg");
        image9.setIcon(hyunnie);
        image9.setSize(200,200);
        image9.setVisible(true);
        image9.setToolTipText("Seohyun Seo Juhyun");
        gamepanel.add(image9);



        controls = new JPanel();
        controls.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        controls.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Control"));

        JButton newGame = new JButton("New Game");
        newGame.addActionListener(new NewButtonListener());
        controls.add(newGame, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        JButton exitGame = new JButton("Exit");
        exitGame.addActionListener(end);
        controls.add(exitGame, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        //controls.add(text, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainpanel.add(gamepanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainpanel.add(controls, BorderLayout.EAST);

        mainpanel.setVisible(true);

        process jj = new process(); 

        image1.addActionListener(jj);
        image2.addActionListener(jj);
        image3.addActionListener(jj);
        image4.addActionListener(jj);
        image5.addActionListener(jj);
        image6.addActionListener(jj);
        image7.addActionListener(jj);
        image8.addActionListener(jj);
        image9.addActionListener(jj);


    }

    class process implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource().equals(image1))
            {
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

                ImageIcon pic=new ImageIcon("jung.jpg");
                piclabel=new JLabel();
                piclabel.setIcon(pic);
                piclabel.setToolTipText("Your guide! This is Jessica Jung");
                controls.add(piclabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);






            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image2))
            {
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

                ImageIcon pic=new ImageIcon("kwon.jpg");
                piclabel=new JLabel();
                piclabel.setIcon(pic);
                piclabel.setToolTipText("Your guide! This is Yuri Kwon");
                controls.add(piclabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image3))
            {
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

                ImageIcon pic=new ImageIcon("hwang.jpg");
                piclabel=new JLabel();
                piclabel.setIcon(pic);
                piclabel.setToolTipText("Your guide! This is Tiffany Hwang");
                controls.add(piclabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image4))
            {
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

                ImageIcon pic=new ImageIcon("lee.jpg");
                piclabel=new JLabel();
                piclabel.setIcon(pic);
                piclabel.setToolTipText("Your guide! This is Sunny Lee");
                controls.add(piclabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image5))
            {
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

                ImageIcon pic=new ImageIcon("choi.jpg");
                piclabel=new JLabel();
                piclabel.setIcon(pic);
                piclabel.setToolTipText("Your guide! This is Sooyoung Choi");
                controls.add(piclabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image6))
            {
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

                ImageIcon pic=new ImageIcon("kimh.jpg");
                piclabel=new JLabel();
                piclabel.setIcon(pic);
                piclabel.setToolTipText("Your guide! This is Hyoyeon Kim");
                controls.add(piclabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image7))
            {
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

                ImageIcon pic=new ImageIcon("im.jpg");
                piclabel=new JLabel();
                piclabel.setIcon(pic);
                piclabel.setToolTipText("Your guide! This is Yoona Im");
                controls.add(piclabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image8))
            {
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

                ImageIcon pic=new ImageIcon("kimt.jpg");
                piclabel=new JLabel();
                piclabel.setIcon(pic);
                piclabel.setToolTipText("Your guide! This is Taeyeon Kim");
                controls.add(piclabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            }

            else if(e.getSource().equals(image9))
            {
                image1.setVisible(false);
                image2.setVisible(false);
                image3.setVisible(false);
                image4.setVisible(false);
                image5.setVisible(false);
                image6.setVisible(false);
                image7.setVisible(false);
                image8.setVisible(false);
                image9.setVisible(false);
                text.setVisible(false);

                ImageIcon pic=new ImageIcon("seo.jpg");
                piclabel=new JLabel();
                piclabel.setIcon(pic);
                piclabel.setToolTipText("Your guide! This is Juhyun Seo");
                controls.add(piclabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            }           
        }


    }

    class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    class NewButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
                image1.setVisible(true);
                image2.setVisible(true);
                image3.setVisible(true);
                image4.setVisible(true);
                image5.setVisible(true);
                image6.setVisible(true);
                image7.setVisible(true);
                image8.setVisible(true);
                image9.setVisible(true);
                piclabel.setVisible(false);
                j1.setVisible(false);

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (1st thing, instead of a 3x3 grid with 9 cells, have a 2x2 grid with 4 cells).

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819669/absolute-positioning-graphic-jpanel-inside-jframe-blocked-by-blank-sections/11820847#11820847) for some ideas about how to "cut" your image...

Answer (score 3):

> that will transfer a particular button to the free space in the
>   bottom-right most area of the Photo Puzzle Panel

Your `controls` panel is using a `BorderLayout`, but you're already using the `NORTH` and `SOUTH` positions.

I would try using either a `GridLayout` or a `GridBagLayout`.  The `GridBagLayout` can be configured to maintain the preferred size of the buttons...

The other problem is you've made you frame un-resiable, making difficult for the new button to become visible (or at least I did because I wasn't using any images ;)).  I personally can't stand non-resizable windows, but that's me ;)

If you have control over the size of the images, you could simply create a blank/transparent image and set it as the default icon for the `picLabel`, adding to the `controls` panel at startup.  Then all you should need to do is change the label's icon as you need.