# Anybody know of a way to do absolute positioning whilst still using a layout manager?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

Just wondering if there is any way to do absolute positioning for a `JPanel` without using a null layout. My end goal is to have the `JComponent` instances move relative to the size of the frame (and thus the panel) whilst still being able to put them exactly where I want them with absolute positioning.

Comment: Seems an opportunity to make your own ScalingAbsoluteLayout.. It would be senseless for people to code an AbsoluteLayout or NullLayout, but search. GUI builders might use such a layout manager.

Comment: Maybe [GroupLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) or [SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) is appropriate?

Comment: Probably not quite what you're looking for, but as a reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819669/absolute-positioning-graphic-jpanel-inside-jframe-blocked-by-blank-sections/11822601#11822601) makes use of percentage based positioning layout (not really meant for components, but it gives you some idea of the complexity of the task)

Comment: `GridBagLayout` also has constraints that allow you to specify how components grow/shrink as the panel size changes. So does the `GridLayout`. Without a specific requirement we can't provide a specific suggestion.

Comment: *"Thank you."* Tip: add @camickr (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* a person of a new comment.